# Importing data from SharePoint to Power BI and getting error Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I am trying to import the data into power BI from Sharepoint but i am getting two different error in two different scenario -

Scenario 1 i tried - i put the site address with main folder

Result - It is taking me to list of reports but showing only ALL DEFAULT SYSTEM FILES NOT THE ONE I CREATED

Scenario 2 i tried - i put the site address with sub sub folder

Result - I am getting below error -

Unable to Connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect
Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:
OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)"

Could you please help here to resolve this issue.

While importing the data from Sharepoint, i tried with both options, Sharepoint online list & Sharepoint list.

Regards,
SK

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to import from SharePoint lists, whether to PowerBI or Excel, it will ask you to input the SharePoint site URL.

Please note that **it's not** the **SharePoint list** URL the one you need to provide but the **SharePoint site** URL.

After you provide the site URL, then you will see the files/lists from the site that you can use as data source tables in PowerBI/Excel and import them.

The 404 error you described happens when PowerBI/Excel doesn't find the site resources (lists, documents, etc.).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

i fixed my problem by importing data from sharepoint using WEB option instead of using sharepoint list & sharepoint online list

While importing sharepoint data using WEB, we have to provide complete address of file along with file name and extension (e.g. for excel file - filename.xlsx)

Please let me know if there is any other option available

Comment: Since there is SharePoint related options there, for newbies it is easy to get confused. You saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. Get data with "SharePoint folder". The important point is that site url template should be like that:

```
https://OrganizationName.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/
```

Note: Don't add the document name to the end of url.

Answer (score 0):

There is a window that appears when you try to connect with Sharepoint and if you the credentials/auth method it will work.

Comment: This is not an answer, please consider leaving a comment instead.

Comment: @Gustavo Moura - i have top level admin access to sharepoint. but when i am trying to import file from sharepoint, i am getting the window that you mentioned but in that instead of reports i am getting the objects